# Expectation Value with exponential function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've got a short question about the existence of the expectation value.

Let $X$ be a random variable without further knowledge about it (e.g. if it has a density or not).
If I know $\mathbb{E}(e^X)<\infty$ can I conclude that $\mathbb{E}(|X|)<\infty$, hence the expectation value of X exists?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems unlikely if $X$ is heavy tailed on the left

Comment: ok, maybe I've got an idea. What about $$\mathbb{E}(e^X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\mathbb{E}(X^k)<\infty.$$ Therefore $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ exists and so E[|X|]?

Comment: That argument fails if most of the $\mathbb{E}(X^k)$ are $\pm\infty$

Comment: But if there's one term $\pm\infty$, everything explodes?

Comment: If one $\mathbb{E}(X^k)$ term is $\pm \infty$ then so are many more

Comment: if most of the $\mathbb{E}[X^k]=\pm\infty$ how can the sum converge? I mean how can the limit be unique?

Comment: That is why the argument can fail

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $X=-2,-2^2, -2^3,-2^4,\ldots$ with probabilities  $\frac12,\frac1{2^2},\frac1{2^3},\frac1{{2^4}},\ldots$ respectively

then  $\mathbb{E}(e^X)$  is certainly finite and between $0$ and $e^{-2}$, in fact about $0.07228849$,

but $\mathbb{E}(X)=-\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}(|X|)=\infty$.

What is true is that $\mathbb{E}(e^{|X|})\lt \infty \implies \mathbb{E}(|X|)\lt \infty$.

Comment: Very nicely done.

Comment: How did you find this example?

Comment: Yup that's right, thank you!

Comment: @user7427029 I invented it - a negative version of the St Petersburg problem

Comment: Interesting. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the expectation be $0.0725788$?

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate  I get $\frac12 e^{-2} + \frac14 e^{-4} + \frac18 e^{-8} + \frac1{16} e^{-16}+\cdots$ $\approx 0.067667642+0.004578910+0.000041933+0.000000007+\cdots$

Comment: I see... I just used the geometric series formula with ratio $\frac 1{2e^2}$ to get the value I posted.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate It is not a geometric series:  for example the third term is $\frac18 e^{-8}$ while in a geometric series it would be $\frac18 e^{-6}$